# A Question about Magento Scheduling?

Tags: cron, schedule

I have a cron setup to run every hour. The magento cron setting **"Schedule Ahead for"** parameter has a setting of 15. Right now when the cron executes, it runs my custom script for 15 times. What I want is to execute the script only once. My question is this. If I change the schedule to make it 1, will it affect the rest of the operations? How to handle this issue from my custom module? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is yes on Server setup. However, for individual setups. This will be your best friend.

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html

This will get you started in the basic on Cron as you can actually start seeing on the cron.php(sh) running even from the core setup and hopefully you newly installed module if setup properly. There is much to learn and best of luck.